# Database - how to fill foreign keys columns in a table - many to many relationship

Tags: sql, database, database-design, relational-database

[image]

This is my database given at university lecture. I have to create and fill the tables with data. I do not understand the need of Book_Genre table. Is it not enough to have Book and Genre tables ? I belived I got it but when I had to fill the tables I did not know hoy to fill the ISBN columns in Genre and Book_Genre tables. I do not want to put a single book in a certain genre and I want to write only different genre names in the column dedicated for genre`s name.  I do not understand the relation between these 3 tables.

Comment: The book_genre table sets up a many to many relationship.  That means a book can have more than one genre and a genre can apply to more than one book.  In fact, in real life, you would want a simliar relationship with books and authors.  If the textbook for your course does not address that, I've heard good things about the book, Database Design for Mere Mortals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This database design is incorrect. If the relationship between book and Genre is many to many, then the PK of Book should not be in Genre table.

The symbols are also incorrect. The many symbol should be at the book table side not the Book_Genre side (assuming look across notation). If you use Look Here notation, then you should have the many relation at the Genre moved to the Book_Genre table.

In addition, the relationship between Author and book should be many-to-many